# Run the source code in org mode asynchronously

Tags: org-mode

Upon running shell command from the org source code:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC shell
rsync -av ~/Documents \
    --include=~/Public  /media/me/disk/
#+END_SRC
```

it stopped and waiting, cannot do nothing else.

How could run the source code asynchronously?

Comment: Please do some research before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package [ob-async](https://github.com/astahlman/ob-async) lets you execute source blocks asynchronously.

Install and enable the package. Then add `:async` to the header args:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC shell :async
rsync -av ~/Documents \
    --include=~/Public  /media/me/disk/
#+END_SRC
```